# Running Appium Suite having two apps interacting with each other in one test

Tags: java, continuous-integration, appium

I have an appium test suite which has two apps interacting with each other in one single test.
On Local my flow is:

1. Start Emulator1 and Emulator2
2. Start Appium Sever on 4723
3. Start Appium Server on 4725
   Run the TestNG suite or mvn test.

Now I want these two apps to run on two devices that are hosted on BrowserStack or any other Cloud Devices provider.
(I do not want to run by creating emulators on Cloud VMs)

**This is what i tried so far:**
BrowserStack does not provide(according to what I understood) the option to run two apps on two devices in one Build. And so do other cloud device providers.

Our CI is currently on Github Actions. The standard Windows and Linux runners do not provide hardware acceleration. The Mac Image is too expensive and also emulators fail to start sometimes. I used ReactiveCircus' Android Emulator action.

We can use this action on Linux Larger Runner(4 vCPUs) but that requires us to buy Team or Enterprise plan which we are not looking to do currently.

Also this action has script as a required option so I am assuming it also runs one app on matrix of devices and not 2 apps simultaneously on 2 devices.

Obviously we can make use of other VM options which support nested virtualization like Azure and Digital Ocean ones.

But what I am thinking is I am missing something regarding the cloud device platforms capability of running two apps on two devices simultaneously. So I am interested to know if someone has faced this problem and found a solution.